# Usage of "above" to refer to a previous item in a text

Tags: grammar

If I want to refer to a previous remark in a text, do I write "the remark above" or "the above remark"?

Answer (score 1):

I checked Google Ngram for **the table above VS the above table; the list above VS the above list,the remark above VS the above remark**.

I think it is just difference in writing style. I don't think there are nuances between these, but let's wait for other answers.

[image]

Comment: I would see 'the remark above' as more straightforward because the 'what' (the remark') is separated from the 'where' (above), while 'the above remark' mixes them and causes me to have a slight stutter in understanding when I read it.